# Does Java use indexes for Data structure like Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, indexing

When we create a Collection (ArrayList,HashMap) in Java, does Java internally create some kind of index for faster retrieval of data ? In Oracle we have to manually create indexes but what is the technique (if any) used in Java

Comment: What sort of index were you expecting from an ArrayList? It's efficiently accessed by numeric index, because it's backed by an array... but there's no index if you want to look for other properties. Databases and in-memory collections are really pretty different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `ArrayList`, each `Object` has a unique index (even duplicate objects).

An object can easily be accessed by its index using `ArrayList.get()`. The index is based on the order Objects are added (assuming you haven't sorted the `ArrayList` or otherwise changed the order). When an object is removed from an `ArrayList`, all elements in front of it (with a larger index) are shifted to the left so that their indices become `index - 1`.

A `HashMap` uses a slightly more complex indexing scheme...

For a `HashMap`, all indexing information is hidden from you first of all, so you don't really need to know this unless you want to understand its internal workings (which is a good thing!) It does use indexing however... `HashMap`s use an array of `Entry`s (its own implementation of `Map.Entry`) to store information.  `Entry` represents a node in a linked list (not to be confused with the object `java.util.LinkedList`) and it stores a key, a value, and the next node in the linked list.

The index of an entry in a `HashMap` is simply `h & (length - 1)` where `h` is the `hashCode` of the key, passed through a custom hashing method internal to the `java.util` package (you won't be able to access it), and `length` is a power-of-two integer representing the size of the array of `Entry`s (this will automatically grow if need be).

Of course there may be some collisions if two keys end up computing the same hash. This is why `HashMap` uses an array of linked lists. In case of a collision, where two `Entry`s have the same hash, one can be tagged to the end of the other.

To get an object in `HashMap`, the index is calculated from the key you provide through `get(key)` and the relevant `Entry` is retrieved from the array of `Entry`s. Now that the map has the first node in a linked list, it will iterate over all elements of this linked list until it finds the key equal to the key you provided.

Answer (score 0):

yes.. Java does hide these implementation details. But for the performance that java provides, there may be some indexing technique internally used. When you refer to "Oracle" I believe its the SQL or database software and not a language like Java.